# copy in powershell does not work as excpected

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I have the following powershell script that not quite work as I thought it would. I want to copy the new created file in the source folder ($folder) to my destination folder ($DestFolder), but no file is copied. Anyone see what could be wrong?

```
$SourceFolder = 'd:\temp\' # Enter the root path you want to monitor.
$folder = 'd:\temp' # Enter the root path you want to monitor.
$Destfolder = 'd:\temp2\' # Enter the root path you want to monitor.
$global:MySourceFolder = 'd:\temp\' # Enter the root path you want to monitor.
$global:MyDestfolder = 'd:\temp2\' # Enter the root path you want to monitor.
$filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here.

# In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if required.                          
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}


Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
#Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green
Write-Host "path :  $MyDestfolder$name" -fore green
Copy-Item (Join-Path $MySourceFolder $name) ($Destfolder)
Out-File -FilePath d:\temp\filechange\outlog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is working as intended. If the copy actually is part of the action, try moving that line inside the action script block.

The variable $name is empty outside the action scriptblock since the ObjectEvent has its own scope. If you need to access this variable from outside the Action scriptblock you could declare the variable using $global:name.

The following really should work (replace with this but save a copy of your code so you've got a backup first)

```
$folder = 'd:\temp'
$Destfolder = 'd:\temp2'
$filter = '*.*'

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{ 
    IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

    Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green
    Copy-Item -Path (Join-Path $folder $name) -Destination $Destfolder
    Out-File -FilePath "d:\temp\filechange\outlog.txt" -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
}
```

Comment: Thanks I missed the action part, but after I placed it inside the action and tried this...

    Write-Host "path : $folder$name" -fore green

I can see that the actual $folder path is empty for some reason, that must be why the copy-item isnt working, but I don't know why..

Comment: That makes no sense to me... You shouldn't be able to create the filesystemwatcher-object without a proper path.

By the way, to get the path you'd expect in your write-host you should add an "\" inbetween the variables; like this "$folder\$name"

Comment: I changed to this "Write-Host "path :  $folder\$name" -fore green" and that write out "path: \filename.jpg", weird......

Comment: I'd close/reopen PowerShell and run the whole thing from the start to make sure you can actually create that FileSystemWatcher-object.

Comment: I do that before any change I do to the script, I can also see that when I create a new file this change is reflected in the d:\temp\filechange\outlog.txt file. So that must mean the FileSystemWatcher Object works, right?

Comment: Yes that would seem likely. Did you make the $name variable global? 
If so, what do you get if you type Write-Output "$folder\$name" on the command line after all of the code has run atleast once and a file has been created to trigger the event? And please update your original post to reflect the changes you've made to the script.

Comment: I have updated the original post code, when I use global variables I can see that this line print out the path and the filename correct "Write-Host "path :  $MyDestfolder$name" -fore green" but it still does not copy the file from "temp" folder to "temp2" folder

Comment: You are using different variables now for a few things. Your FileSystemWatcher for instance is using the original $folder while you join-path using $MySourceFolder.

Comment: Yes, but the path of "$folder" and "$MySourceFolder" is the same, its just the ending "\" that differ, so that should not matter, right?...